# Python: Animating two lists of lines using matplotlib.animation but only shows one set of lines at a time

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, simultaneous

Trying to plot persuit curves with spiraling in lines and a shrinking, rotating polygon with corners at each of the current points
problem = can't get both line of sight lines and main lines to simultaneously plot
The figure flicks back and forth between the shrinking polygon(described by SightLine) and the main persuit curves (MainLines)

When individually animated one at a time, the polygon and pursuit curves plot fine but I just can't get them to work together on the same figure.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
%matplotlib notebook

plt.style.use('dark_background')


NumOfPoints = 6
deltaT = 0.005
duration = 50
steps = int(duration / deltaT)
speed = 0.2
num = 0

CurrentXPoints = []
CurrentYPoints = []
DeltaX = np.zeros(NumOfPoints)
DeltaY = np.zeros(NumOfPoints)
MagnitudeDelta = np.zeros(NumOfPoints)
VelocityX = np.zeros(NumOfPoints)
VelocityY = np.zeros(NumOfPoints)



  
#Creates Initial Points by equally spacing the points around a polygon inscribed around circle
for i in range(0,NumOfPoints): 
    x = np.cos(((i/NumOfPoints)*2)*np.pi)
    y = np.sin(((i/NumOfPoints)*2)*np.pi)

    CurrentXPoints.append(x)
    CurrentYPoints.append(y)

AllXPoints = np.array([CurrentXPoints])
AllYPoints = np.array([CurrentYPoints])

#Fills out both AllXPoints and AllYPoints with all points in duration 

for i in range(int(steps)):
    
    for j in range(0,NumOfPoints-1): #Calculates deltaX and deltaY at this timestep
        DeltaX[j] = CurrentXPoints[j+1] - CurrentXPoints[j]
        DeltaY[j] = CurrentYPoints[j+1] - CurrentYPoints[j]
    
    DeltaX[NumOfPoints-1] = CurrentXPoints[0] - CurrentXPoints[NumOfPoints-1]
    DeltaY[NumOfPoints-1] = CurrentYPoints[0] - CurrentYPoints[NumOfPoints-1]
    
    
    
    for j in range(0,NumOfPoints): # calculats new X and Y Points
        MagnitudeDelta[j] = ((DeltaX[j])**2 + (DeltaY[j])**2)**(1/2)
        VelocityX[j] = speed * (DeltaX[j]/MagnitudeDelta[j])
        VelocityY[j] = speed * (DeltaY[j]/MagnitudeDelta[j])
        CurrentXPoints[j] += deltaT * VelocityX[j]
        CurrentYPoints[j] += deltaT * VelocityY[j]

    CurrentXPointsArr = np.array(CurrentXPoints)
    CurrentYPointsArr = np.array(CurrentYPoints)
    
    AllXPoints = np.vstack((AllXPoints,CurrentXPointsArr))
    AllYPoints = np.vstack((AllYPoints,CurrentYPointsArr))



fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xlim(-2,2)
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)


MainLines = []
SightLines= []
AllLines = MainLines + SightLines

for i in range(NumOfPoints):
    line, = ax.plot([AllXPoints[j][i] for j in range(steps)], [AllYPoints[j][i] for j in range(steps)])
    MainLines.append(line)
    SightLines.append(line)
  

 
def UpdateMain(num, AllXPoints, AllYPoints, MainLines):
    
    
    
    for line in MainLines:
    
        position = MainLines.index(line)
        line.set_data([AllXPoints[i][position] for i in range(num)], [AllYPoints[i][position] for i in range(num)])
        
    
    
def UpdateSight(num, AllXPoints, AllYPoints, SightLines):
    
    for line in SightLines:
        position = SightLines.index(line)

        if position < (NumOfPoints-1):
            line.set_data([AllXPoints[num][position],AllXPoints[num][position+1]],
                         [AllYPoints[num][position],AllYPoints[num][position+1]])
        else:
            line.set_data([AllXPoints[num][position],AllXPoints[num][0]],
                         [AllYPoints[num][position],AllYPoints[num][0]])

    
    
            
        
ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, UpdateMain,steps, fargs=[AllXPoints, AllYPoints, MainLines],
                  interval=1, blit=True)
          
ani2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, UpdateSight,steps, fargs=[AllXPoints, AllYPoints, SightLines],
                  interval=1, blit=True)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use only one `FuncAnimation` that updates *all* the artists.
The main problem of your code are the lines

```
for i in range(NumOfPoints):
    line, = ax.plot([AllXPoints[j][i] for j in range(steps)], [AllYPoints[j][i] for j in range(steps)])
    MainLines.append(line)
    SightLines.append(line)
```

where you are creating one artist (`line`) and assign it to two different lists. If you create 2 different lines for each list, then the output is as expected.

Full working code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
%matplotlib notebook

plt.style.use('dark_background')


NumOfPoints = 6
deltaT = 0.005
duration = 50
steps = int(duration / deltaT)
speed = 0.2
num = 0

CurrentXPoints = []
CurrentYPoints = []
DeltaX = np.zeros(NumOfPoints)
DeltaY = np.zeros(NumOfPoints)
MagnitudeDelta = np.zeros(NumOfPoints)
VelocityX = np.zeros(NumOfPoints)
VelocityY = np.zeros(NumOfPoints)


def update(num, AllXPoints, AllYPoints, MainLines, SightLines):
    out = []
    out.append(UpdateMain(num, AllXPoints, AllYPoints, MainLines))
    out.append(UpdateSight(num, AllXPoints, AllYPoints, SightLines))
    return out
 
def UpdateMain(num, AllXPoints, AllYPoints, MainLines):    
    for line in MainLines:
        position = MainLines.index(line)
        line.set_data([AllXPoints[i][position] for i in range(num)], [AllYPoints[i][position] for i in range(num)])
    return MainLines
        
    
    
def UpdateSight(num, AllXPoints, AllYPoints, SightLines): 
    for line in SightLines:
        position = SightLines.index(line)

        if position < (NumOfPoints-1):
            line.set_data([AllXPoints[num][position],AllXPoints[num][position+1]],
                         [AllYPoints[num][position],AllYPoints[num][position+1]])
        else:
            line.set_data([AllXPoints[num][position],AllXPoints[num][0]],
                         [AllYPoints[num][position],AllYPoints[num][0]])
    return SightLines

  
#Creates Initial Points by equally spacing the points around a polygon inscribed around circle
for i in range(0,NumOfPoints): 
    x = np.cos(((i/NumOfPoints)*2)*np.pi)
    y = np.sin(((i/NumOfPoints)*2)*np.pi)

    CurrentXPoints.append(x)
    CurrentYPoints.append(y)

AllXPoints = np.array([CurrentXPoints])
AllYPoints = np.array([CurrentYPoints])

#Fills out both AllXPoints and AllYPoints with all points in duration 
for i in range(int(steps)):
    for j in range(0,NumOfPoints-1): #Calculates deltaX and deltaY at this timestep
        DeltaX[j] = CurrentXPoints[j+1] - CurrentXPoints[j]
        DeltaY[j] = CurrentYPoints[j+1] - CurrentYPoints[j]

    DeltaX[NumOfPoints-1] = CurrentXPoints[0] - CurrentXPoints[NumOfPoints-1]
    DeltaY[NumOfPoints-1] = CurrentYPoints[0] - CurrentYPoints[NumOfPoints-1]

    for j in range(0,NumOfPoints): # calculats new X and Y Points
        MagnitudeDelta[j] = ((DeltaX[j])**2 + (DeltaY[j])**2)**(1/2)
        VelocityX[j] = speed * (DeltaX[j]/MagnitudeDelta[j])
        VelocityY[j] = speed * (DeltaY[j]/MagnitudeDelta[j])
        CurrentXPoints[j] += deltaT * VelocityX[j]
        CurrentYPoints[j] += deltaT * VelocityY[j]

    CurrentXPointsArr = np.array(CurrentXPoints)
    CurrentYPointsArr = np.array(CurrentYPoints)
    AllXPoints = np.vstack((AllXPoints,CurrentXPointsArr))
    AllYPoints = np.vstack((AllYPoints,CurrentYPointsArr))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xlim(-2,2)
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

MainLines = []
SightLines= []
AllLines = MainLines + SightLines

for i in range(NumOfPoints):
    line1, = ax.plot([AllXPoints[j][i] for j in range(steps)], [AllYPoints[j][i] for j in range(steps)])
    line2, = ax.plot([AllXPoints[j][i] for j in range(steps)], [AllYPoints[j][i] for j in range(steps)])
    MainLines.append(line1)
    SightLines.append(line2)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, steps, fargs=[AllXPoints, AllYPoints, MainLines, SightLines], interval=1, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: Result of the animation showing a shrinking hexagon and spiraling curves extending from each corner]

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Comment: You're welcome. If that solution resolved your problem, consider accepting the answer using the checkmark on the left to close the topic. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)